How disable sorting Dictionary in Swagger
I'm using niget Swashbuckle.AspNetCore version 6.7.
I have code:
public class DataResponse
{
    public Dictionary<string, decimal> Info { get; set; }
}

public class DataResponseExample : IExamplesProvider<DataResponse>
{
    public DataResponse GetExamples()
        => new DataResponse
        {
            Info = new Dictionary<string, decimal>
            {
                { "100", 842.123123m },
                { "40", 842.123123m },
                { "10", 842.123123m },
                { "1", 842.123123m },
                { "0.1", 842.123123m },
                { "0.01", 842.123123m },
                { "0.05", 842.123123m },
                { "0.001", 842.123123m },
            }
        };
}

And waiting that on swagger page sorting of dictionary will be in same order, but in fact i see:
{
  "info": {
    "1": 842.123123,
    "10": 842.123123,
    "40": 842.123123,
    "100": 842.123123,
    "0.1": 842.123123,
    "0.01": 842.123123,
    "0.05": 842.123123,
    "0.001": 842.123123
  }
}

Swagger sorted dictonary by key automaticly, and how does disable sorting?

A Dictionary does not have any particular or defined order, so the result of iterating or serialization is (more or less) random. If you are using Dictionary, your code should not rely on any particular order. If you need a particular order for your entries, use a different datastructure. For instance a List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>

I tried, but result is not needed format:
{
"info": [
{
"key": "100",
"value": 842.123123
},
{
"key": "40",
"value": 842.123123
},
{
"key": "10",
"value": 842.123123
}
]
}

Well of course, because in terms of JSON, one is an array and the other one an object. Generally saying: When you need a specific order (that cannot be recreated by some sort() function) you have to use something array-like, when you need something object-like you can't have a specific order.

The whole problem seems to be a bit like an XY problem: Ie why do you need your object to have a particular order? Respectively why do you need your data to be an object and not a list?

The behavior of Dictionary<TKey, TValue> is driven by the hash table implementation, which is inherently unordered. The hash table distributes elements into different buckets based on the hash values of the keys, and the hash values and bucket positions do not consider the insertion order. This is the fundamental reason why the order of elements in a Dictionary is unpredictable. So this issue is unrelated to Swagger.
So we can use List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>> to ensure the order of data as an alternative solution to this problem.
DataController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using WebApplication11.Models;

namespace WebApplication11.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class DataController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<DataResponse> GetData()
        {
            var data = new DataResponse
            {
                Info = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>
                {
                    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("100", 842.123123m),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("40", 842.123123m),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("10", 842.123123m),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("1", 842.123123m),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("0.1", 842.123123m),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("0.01", 842.123123m),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("0.05", 842.123123m),
                    new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("0.001", 842.123123m)
                }
            };
            return Ok(data);
        }
    }
}

DataResponse.cs
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace WebApplication11.Models
{
    public class DataResponse
    {
        public List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>? Info { get; set; }
    }
}

DataResponseExample.cs
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;

namespace WebApplication11.Models
{
    public class DataResponseExample : IExamplesProvider<DataResponse>
    {
        public DataResponse GetExamples()
        {
            return new DataResponse
            {
                Info = new List<KeyValuePair<string, decimal>>
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("100", 842.123123m),
                new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("40", 842.123123m),
                new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("10", 842.123123m),
                new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("1", 842.123123m),
                new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("0.1", 842.123123m),
                new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("0.01", 842.123123m),
                new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("0.05", 842.123123m),
                new KeyValuePair<string, decimal>("0.001", 842.123123m)
            }
            };
        }
    }
}

Test Result


If you read the comments below the question, I already suggested that, but OP claims, they don't want a list- like result, but an object ...
